# ASP Image control not Picking up ImageUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have image saved in C: drive of server and my ASP.NET web application is picking them up and showing them in an ASP:Image tag but its not working, i have checked the path  a 100 times its very fine.
Here is the path of image

```
C://Temp//image.png
```

and here is the code inside a girdView templateFiled

```
 <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Picture") %>' ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="90%" Height="20%" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder in your web application and copy the image there. Then refer to it using a relative path.

If you refer to this image in C: drive eventually when you host the application all users of this website will not see the image. Because a web browser cannot access an image in C: drive of the web server.

Comment: well the problem is that, a webService is storing images in this folder and a WebApp is accessing these images.I if use some folder in WebApplication's folder how i will be able to store them via WebService.?

Comment: Ok then you have to a bit of work to get the correct url :-D Read this and you'll get the hang of it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Comment: Otherwise create a virtual directory in IIS to point to your images folder. then you could refer to your images as you normally would with fully qualified url.